# Visual studio, how to output time taken to build?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, compiler-construction, time, build, switch-statement

I'm using visual studio 2005. I rememeber in the back of my mind there's a way to output the time taken to build a given project.

Can anyone remember what that switch is?

Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Project Settings -> Build Timing

should work.

EDIT: My bad, thats VS2008 :(

In 2005 you might get the build times by changing MSBuild output verbosity to Detailed or Diagnostic from Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build & Run

Comment: Neat, I had no idea that option was there!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a visual studio Macro to show the exact time it takes to build a solution. Have a look at this answer: 
[Awesome Visual Studio Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523220/awesome-visual-studio-macros/2112181#2112181)