# Measuring total solution build time in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, build-process

Does any know if there is any native mechanism to report on the **total solution build time** in Visual Studio 2008? You can change the build verbosity to report build times per project as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82128/displaying-build-times-in-visual-studio) or report total build time from msbuild  but I’d like to see this in the IDE across an entire solution containing many projects. Short of creating custom pre and post build events, does anyone know if there’s any native output for total build time? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Troy, maybe it's not relevant any more, but I tried the VS extension BuildMonitor, and it seems to work nicely: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danielperssson.BuildMonitor

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, the correct answer is "No, you can't report on total solution build time directly within Visual Studio".

Comment: Correct answer is yes. See splintor answer bellow.

Comment: Correct answer is no - the question was for Visual Studio 2008 and I don't think splintor bellowed at all, he was actually rather polite :)

Comment: Still correct as of VS 2015 :(

Comment: [Have you tried this solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523220/awesome-visual-studio-macros/2112181#2112181) It works well in VS2010, and I think it should work in older versions as well (not in newer though because it's a VB macro).

Answer (score 17):

Not native and not not for VS 2008 (currently only for VS 2010), but [the VSCommands 2010 extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf) provides these statistics.

See also: [VS 2010: Prevent display of Build Summary in the output window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082049)

Comment: This VS extension was exactly what I was looking to find.  Thanks.

Comment: Website for the extension is here, so you can find support for VS2012 as well: http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/

Answer (score 14):

MSBuild will show the total build time when you run it from the command prompt, e.g:

```
> msbuild MySolution.sln
...
Time Elapsed 00:00:36.94
```

Comment: Sure, I’m aware of the command line option, I’m looking for something within VS though so it is visible during normal development.

Answer (score 9):

There's also an easy way to measure the build time **per project** in Visual Studio 2010. I'm pretty sure it will work in Visual Studio 2008, too. All you have to do is to go to  **Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run** and set the MSBuild project build output verbosity to "Normal" or "Detailed" (I recommend "Normal", as detailed gives too much information).

Comment: "Normal" does not output the total build time if you have more than a single project inside your solution. Neither does "Detailed".

Answer (score 3):

I think you could probably hook into the OnBuildBegin and OnBuildDone events

http://visualstudiohacks.com/general/customize-your-project-build-process/

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting avenue to follow.

Comment: Yes, meanwhile this was answered somewhere else, have a look at this macro:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523220/awesome-visual-studio-macros/2112181#2112181

Answer (score 3):

In VC++2008, there is the "Build Timing' option in Tools / Options / Projects and solutions / VC++ Project Settings

Comment: This is only for C++ projects