# VS 2010: Prevent display of Build Summary in the output window

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When you build in 'quiet' mode in Visual Studio 2008, the output looks like this:

```
Compile complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings
------ Build started: Project: JLTA.JBS.UI.Office.VSTODocument, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
------ Build started: Project: JLTA.JBS.UI.Office.VSTOWorkbook, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
------ Build started: Project: JLTA.JBS.UI.GeneralLedgerUpdater, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

Compile complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings
========== Build: 86 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is good because the last two lines of the output quickly show me the result of the build (success/fail).

In Visual Studio 2010 Microsoft added a build summary *after* this. So, when I build in VS 2010 with the same settings (eg. 'quiet' option), I get the following displayed after the stuff that's already shown in VS 2008:

```
------ Build started: Project: JLTA.JBS.UI.TestBed, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
========== Build: 78 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Build Summary
-------------
00:06.772 - Success - UI\TestBed\JLTA.JBS.UI.TestBed.csproj
00:05.926 - Success - UI\Main\JLTA.JBS.UI.Main.csproj
... <bunch of lines deleted here>
00:00.035 - Success - Bus\Budget\JLTA.JBS.Bus.Budget.csproj
00:00.032 - Success - Core\JLTA.JBS.Core.csproj

Total build time: 01:06.088
```

This is a step backwards by MS, because now I have to scroll up in the build output window to see whether the build succeeded or not.

Is there any way of getting this back to the old VS 2008 behaviour?

Comment: I'm not convinced that Microsoft have "added" anything. My builds look like the VS2008 output. To get anything more, I have to specify additional options for MSBuild. Could it be a VS add-in that is doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This output is not from Visual Studio or MSBuild, it is provided by the [VSCommands add-in](http://mokosh.co.uk/post/tag/vscommands/) - see [this blog entry](http://mokosh.co.uk/post/2010/05/03/vscommands-2-2-0-0-released/). You can investigate settings for that add-in and see if this summary can be disabled, or remove the add-in so that you no longer see this summary detail.

For those that are interested, I found this with [this Google query](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Build+summary%22+%22Total+build+time%22).

---

[archive.org 2011/12/30 mokosh.co.uk/post/tag/vscommands/](http://web.archive.org/web/20111230192500/http://mokosh.co.uk/post/tag/vscommands/)
[archive.org 2011/09/16 mokosh.co.uk/post/2010/05/03/vscommands-2-2-0-0-released/](http://web.archive.org/web/20110916174135/http://mokosh.co.uk/post/2010/05/03/vscommands-2-2-0-0-released/)

Comment: Yes, currently it is the checkbox here: Tools -> VSCommands -> Options -> IDE Enhancements -> Build -> Show Build statistics in ouptut window.

Answer (score 3):

I get it like VS2008 by selecting "Minimal" for project build output verbosity (Tools --> Options --> Projects and Solutions --> Build and Run)

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the problem as stated for me. I still get a verbose multi-line "build summary" rather than the two line summary in VS2008.

Comment: @Ben Robbins - Perhaps you have some 3rd party tool (MSBuild) or registry setting that has enabled this. Have you disabled all add-ons/external tools and tried building?