# How to display total build time when building a C++ solution with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

How to display total build time when building a C++ solution with Visual Studio 2012? I think the option to turn it on must hide somewhere, but I cannot find it. Thanks.

The answer in [Displaying build times in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82128/displaying-build-times-in-visual-studio) provides different results. It shows build time for each function rather than the total build time in my testing on VS2012.

I want this (borrowed from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082049/vs-2010-prevent-display-of-build-summary-in-the-output-window) for c# solution)

```
Build Summary
-------------
00:06.772 - Success - UI\TestBed\JLTA.JBS.UI.TestBed.csproj
00:05.926 - Success - UI\Main\JLTA.JBS.UI.Main.csproj
... <bunch of lines deleted here>
00:00.035 - Success - Bus\Budget\JLTA.JBS.Bus.Budget.csproj
00:00.032 - Success - Core\JLTA.JBS.Core.csproj

Total build time: 01:06.088  // This line is necessary; the above is optional.
```

Comment: They are different. I tried the answer there before asking question. It shows build time for each functions rather than the total build time.