# Compilation time in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compilation

How can I measure compilation/built time in Visual Studio 2010? Have any advices how can I speed up compilation process?

Comment: What kind of times are you seeing? How many projects do you have in your solution?

Comment: I use C# in .NET 4.0, in my solution are little above 60 projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2112181/459517) suggests a way of showing the build time in the output window for each build.

To both improve and measure build time you could use a product like [Incredibuild](http://www.xoreax.com/).

It is a distributed build tool that uses idle cycles from pc's on your network to improve build times. I worked at a games development company a few years ago who used it and managed to reduce build times from roughly 35 minutes to under 5 minutes.

Note that this is not a free product.

Below is a screenshot showing how this tool integrates with VisualStudio. The muti-coloured bars show which computer is building the code for you, what they are building and the time it is taking them (errors are always shown in red).

[image: Incredibuild Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but it is too advanced tool for my need :)

Comment: @Jacek i've updated my post to include a link showing you how to log the build time to the output window.