# Add Code to the EnvironmentEvents module

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, macros, development-environment

I want to be able to add code/macro to the Environment Events module. How do I do such a thing?
This was a post where I heard of such a thing but I wouldn't know where to start on how to do it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2112181/1055946

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find `EnvironmentEvents` by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to open the Macro Explorer 
and then opening Module1 in `MyMacros`, this will open up in the `Visual Studio Macro Editor`. `EnvironmentEvents` is located there. Then you can learn about macros by reading the [MSDN documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967.aspx)

[image]