# Displaying build times in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I am using  Visual Studio 2013 to execute c++ code.I want to see the execution time of my code.

I performed the following activities

```
Tools -> Options -> Projects and solutions ->VC++ Project Settings->Build timing->yes

**Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run and set the MSBuild project build output verbosity to "Normal"**
```

but it's not working for me.

Comment: The execution time of your code is not the build time.

Answer (score 1):

I use Squared Infinity's [VS Commands](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/) Visual Studio extension which has an option to display a build summary in the output window that lists the time each project took to build.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **compilation time**, as the title of your post suggests, you're in the right direction. [You may want to look at this thread for further help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82128/displaying-build-times-in-visual-studio).

If you want to know **how your code performs at runtime**, that's a different story. You can either insert use datetime variables along with print commands in your code to see the elapsed time in a console window (not very pretty or efficient) or use a profiling tool (much better IMHO).

Personally I use RedGate's [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) and am quite pleased with it. :) I should mention I never tried it with managed C++ but it should work just fine.

Visual Studio also has a [built-in profiling tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx), but I never tried it myself. You might want to take a look at it.

Hope that helps.