# CMake: How to enable build timing, e.g. for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake

I know that "Build Timing" can be enabled in Visual Studio:
[Displaying build times in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82128/displaying-build-times-in-visual-studio)

I wonder, if this option can be enabled from CMake at configuration-time, that is, in a CMakeLists.txt? Similarly, I suspect that there may be other "general" build-related options, for which it may be convenient, if they could be configured from CMakeLists.txt?

Naturally, any such option, if configured in a CMakeLists.txt, may well be ignored, if a given CMake-generator and/or the underlying build-system doesn't support it. So may be another way of phrasing the question is what specific options does some Visual Studio CMake-generator, say for example "Visual Studio 11 Win64", support, and where can I find out about it? I sure tried (Google), but didn't get very far...

Answer (score 1):

This is the global setting of your Visual Studio editor and it is not connected to a solution generated by CMake. Open Visual Studio, set the option and it will be stored in your profile preferences.