# xamarin uwp speed up the building & deployment process

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to make some change and deploy on windows 10 (UWP) but it takes too much time. Is there any option to make it faster ?

I see by using options I could increase the speed of deployment in Android and iOS.

But I couldn't find any such options for UWP.

Help please

Comment: First you'll probably have to run build with [Build Timing enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/132526/7034621) to see what's taking so long.

Comment: I don't understand .Can you please explain ?

Comment: In order to speed build up I would first check which part of the build takes the most. The switch mentioned above makes MSBuild emit timing messages at the end of the build, specifying which part of the build process took how long.

Answer (score 0):

Disable "Compile with .NET Native tool chain". It takes a lot of time to compile using .NET Native tool chain so you'd better enable it only when you are ready to ship the app to customers (don't forget to retest after that).
[image: Screenshot]